# Mostrar select mysql en una tabla html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy seleccionando lo siguiente de mi base de datos `mysql` usando `php`:

```
  $ingresos = 'SELECT sum(cantidad) from cash where operacion="IN"';
  $totalIngresos = mysqli_query($conn, $ingresos);
```

Y lo quiero mostrar en una tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
$html3="<table width=\"80%\" height=\"5%\" border=\"3px\" align=\"center\">
            <tr align=\"center\" style=\"background-color:#9fd9ff \">
                <th><b>Total ingresos</b></th>
                <th>$totalIngresos</th>    
            </tr>"; 
$html3.="</table>";
```

El problema es que lo que he intentado no funciona, el resultado debería ser un número decimal.

¿Alguien me puede indicar el fallo o como hacerlo correctamente? Gracias de antemano.

### Añado el código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ingresos</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "user";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "dbase";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if (!$conn) {
      die("Error en la connexion: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  function filtrado($datos){
      $datos = trim($datos);
      $datos = stripslashes($datos);
      $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
      return $datos;
  }

  $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM cash where operacion="IN"';
  $consulta2 = 'SELECT * FROM cash WHERE operacion="OUT"';
  
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);
  $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta2);

  $ingresos = 'SELECT sum(cantidad) from cash where operacion="IN"';
  $totalIngresos = mysqli_query($conn, $ingresos);
  
  
    $html=
        "<h1 align=\"center\">Ingresos</h1><br>
            <table width=\"80%\" height=\"5%\" border=\"3px\" align=\"center\">
                
            <style>
                table {
                    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 80%;
                }
                
                td, th {
                    border: 1px solid white;
                    text-align: left;
                    padding: 8px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                
                tr:nth-child(even) {
                    background-color: #dddddd;
                }

                .myclass{
                    display:inline-block;
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 20px;
                }
            </style>
            
            <tr align=\"center\" style=\"background-color:#9fd9ff \">
                <td><b>Data</b></td>    
                <td><b>Cantidad</b></td>
                <td><b>Ent</b></td>
                <td><b>Conc</b></td>
            </tr>";
            
            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
            {
                $html.="<tr align=\"center\">                    
                    <td>".filtrado($fila['data_hora'])."</td>
                    <td>".filtrado($fila['cantidad'])."€</td>
                    <td>".filtrado($fila['ent'])."</td>
                    <td>".filtrado($fila['conc'])."</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
            
    $html.="</table>";

    $html2=
    "<br><br><h1 align=\"center\">Gasto</h1><br>
        <table width=\"80%\" height=\"5%\" border=\"3px\" align=\"center\">
                    
        <tr align=\"center\" style=\"background-color:#9fd9ff \">
            <td><b>Data</b></td>    
            <td><b>Cantidad</b></td>
            <td><b>Ent</b></td>
            <td><b>Conc/b></td>
        </tr>";
        
        while($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2))
        {
            $html2.="<tr align=\"center\">                    
                <td>".filtrado($fila2['data_hora'])."</td>
                <td>".filtrado($fila2['cantidad'])."€</td>
                <td>".filtrado($fila2['ent'])."</td>
                <td>".filtrado($fila2['conc'])."</td>
                </tr>";
        }

    $html2.="</table>";
    

    $html3="<br><br><br><table width=\"80%\" height=\"5%\" border=\"3px\" align=\"center\">
                <tr align=\"center\" style=\"background-color:#9fd9ff \">
                    <th><b>Total ingresos</b></th>
                    <th>$totalIngresos</th>    
                </tr>";  
    

    $html3.="</table>";

    echo $html; 
    echo $html2; 
    echo $html3;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Analizando el error en el navegador, pude observar esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124091/discussion-between-excorpion-and-winset).

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas. Gracias por continuar la conversación en el chat.

Comment: Soluciones obtenidas en el chat BTW.

Comment: Sugiero que uses comillas simples, para evitar escribir el contraslash "\" a cada rato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primero que nada debemos empezar revisando la conexión.
Podemos hacerlo simple con:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tecnic";
$password = "admin1234";
$dbname = "personal";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
var_dump($conn);
if (!$conn) {
die("Error en la connexion: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Por otro lado, a tu consulta le falta algo...

```
$ingresos = 'SELECT sum(quantitat) from cash where operacio="IN"';
$totalIngresos = mysqli_query($conn, $ingresos);
```

Para poder desplegar sum(quantitat), debes darle un nombre, por lo que debes cambiar la consulta a:

```
$ingresos = 'SELECT sum(quantitat) as resultado from cash where operacio="IN"';
```

Ya luego en el while que creas, puedes llamar la columna $fila["resultado"];

Finalmente ya puedes agregar los cambios a tu codigo.

Sugiero además usar el CSS separado del PHP y HTML por temas de comodidad y evitar la duplicación constante de código.